# Latronix KVM stopped working after last java update

Tags: software-update, java

I see this error when open jnlp file via javaws manually:
`java.lang.AssertionError: Threading violation: not AppKit thread`

Is there anything I can do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I reverted back to the Apple provided java packages, it fixed my problems.

The article for this download is:

- [Java for OS X 2012-006: How to re-enable the Apple-provided Java SE 6 applet plug-in and Web Start functionality](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5559)

Update: Note that for some people, the Java 7 update works with Lantronix Spiders. I can confirm that a colleague with the same model Macbook Pro has no problems using the latest Java 7 update. Another with a Macbook Air experiences the same issue, which is also resolved by rolling back.

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Comment: I've had the same problem with other KVM vendors...  Seems they're very picky about the *exact* update of Java that you can have.

Comment: Remember to demand an update of your Latronix software from Latronix.

Answer (score 2):

I found that on Lantronix Spider under Console settings, change "KVM Console Deployment" from "Web Start" to "Applet" and it worked again.

Comment: For me it started worked like magic, without any changes